# How to make objects receive shadow in away3d

Tags: flash, 3d, flash-cs5, away3d

I am fairly new to away3d. After putting together a basic scene with shaded objects, I was wondering why they don't case shadows onto each other?

In my example there is a cube above a plane with a directional light above the both. How can I make the cube cast a shadow onto the plane under it?

The example is written using away 3d 3.6

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import away3d.containers.View3D;
import away3d.primitives.Cube;
import away3d.primitives.Plane;
import away3d.lights.DirectionalLight3D;
import away3d.materials.PhongColorMaterial;
import away3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
import flash.geom.Vector3D;


public class Test7 extends MovieClip {

    public var view:View3D;
    public var light:DirectionalLight3D;

    public var cube:Cube;
    public var plane:Plane;     

    public function Test7() {
        // constructor code
        view = new View3D();
        view.x = 200;
        view.y = 200;
        view.z = 150;

        light = new DirectionalLight3D();
        light.direction = new Vector3D(0, -1, 0);
        light.brightness = 5;
        view.scene.addLight(light);

        plane = new Plane();
        plane.material = new PhongColorMaterial(0xCCCCCC);
        plane.width = 1000;
        plane.height = 1000;
        plane.segmentsH = 
        plane.segmentsW = 10;
        plane.y = -100;
        view.scene.addChild(plane);

        cube = new Cube();
        cube.rotationX = 45;
        cube.rotationY = 45;
        cube.segmentsD = 
        cube.segmentsH = 
        cube.segmentsW = 10;
        cube.material = new PhongColorMaterial(0x330099);
        view.scene.addChild(cube);

        addChild(view);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);            
    }

    public function render(e:Event):void {
        view.render();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation of shadows in real-time is too heavy for CPU so it require GPU (Away 3D 4.0+)
 You should bake shadows, diffuse lighting, global illumination,  ambient occlusion, etc. to texture using graphical editor. That will give you static lighting with super high quality because pre-calculation of global illumination can take plenty of time instead of 1\30 second in rea time. To make scene more dynamic You can add environment cube map to the model or primitive lighting.

Here is demo with precomputed shadows:
 http://alternativaplatform.com/ru/demos/temple/
And this one with env map:
 http://alternativaplatform.com/swf/demos/mobilephone/mobilephone.swf

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clarifications. So away 3d 4.0 uses flash player 11, and only flash player 11 makes use of gpu, right? My object casting the shadow is dynamically loaded and moving in the scene, so baking the shadows is not an option. Maybe I have to used away 3d 4.0 after all or leave the feature out :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to add a shadowMethod to your material.

http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/materials/DefaultMaterialBase.html#shadowMethod

http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/materials/methods/FilteredShadowMapMethod.html

Have a look at this demo to see how it's implemented

demo:
http://infiniteturtles.co.uk/projects/away3d4/examples/Intermediate_PerelithKnightMD2/Intermediate_PerelithKnightMD2.html

source:
http://infiniteturtles.co.uk/projects/away3d4/examples/Intermediate_PerelithKnightMD2/srcview/

Comment: Would you know the away3d 3.6 equivalent of this?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be 4.0 code. For 3.6, SimpleShadow seems to be what you are looking for. Have a look at this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/away3d-dev/7xcvc7T3TCY (first message by Fabrice)

Comment: The SimpleShadow seems to be producing a simple "blob" of shadow under the object, but from a few quick tests this is no real calculated shadow cast by a light. I feel like I am missing some flag or similar in my setup that tells objects to receive shadow.